# C# executes command line to compile other C# code

Tags: c#, command-line

Is there a way to execute command line and compile other c# code in a c# program?

Comment: How is this related to `stored-procedures`? Removing that tag...

Comment: @ean5533, the bag of old rope that is the quality of the question aside; you can actually write stored procedures in C# - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_CLR =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the computer you wish to compile the C# code on has a C# compiler installed, it is possible.

Here is some [example](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/108881) code for accessing the command line

```
public void GenerateKeyFile(string path)
{
  string commandLine = " \"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\\SDK\\v2.0\\Bin\\sn.exe\" -k ";
  ProcessStartInfo PSI = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
  PSI.RedirectStandardInput = true;
  PSI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  PSI.RedirectStandardError = true;
  PSI.UseShellExecute = false;
  Process p = Process.Start(PSI);
  System.IO.StreamWriter SW = p.StandardInput;
  System.IO.StreamReader SR = p.StandardOutput;
  SW.WriteLine(commandLine + path);
  SW.Close();
}
```

And how to use the [C# Compiler `csc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379563%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) from the command line

Both references pulled from the first result in Google